# append input box on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

Append a text box to a shape on double click. Right now, its appending a textbox but its appending only at 0,0 coordinates of the window even after using inline styles

```
 function dragend(d) {
                    var self = d3.select(this);
                    // is this the first time I'm dragged?
                    // replace me with a new one
                    if (self.classed('initialDragCircle')) {
                        // append a new inital draggable
                        createInitialDrag();
                        self.attr('class', 'dragCircle');
                    }
                    else if (self.classed('initialDragRect'))
                    {
                        // append a new inital draggable
                        createInitialDrag();
                        self.attr('class', 'dragRect').transition().attr("width", 111).attr("height", 71)
                        self.on('dblclick', function ()
                        {      
                            var coords = d3.mouse(targG.node());
                            var left = coords[0]
                            var top = coords[1];
                            console.log("top is: "+ top +" and left is: "+ left);
                            $('#container').append('<input type=text class"bpmnLabel" value="hi" autofocus style="position:absolute top:'+(top)+ " left:"+left+'"/>');
                        });
                    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you inspect element on your input field `.bpmnLabel ` and look at the `style=""` attribute. are you seeing the `x` and `y` coords you want but they are not being applied?

Comment: It would help everyone to help you if you took the time to create a jsfiddle which exhibits your issue.

Comment: @Mathew sure will do that soon

Comment: @Alan I only see top and left but not x and y. I think html input box doesn't have x and y or does it?

Comment: When I say `x` and `y` I mean are the vales for them placed within `top` and `left`

Comment: @Alan yes i see top and left which are 30 and 355 but still its at 0,0 coords

Comment: @Alan When I try this `$('#mydiv').append('<input type=text class"bpmnLabel" value="hi" autofocus/>').css({"position": "absolute", "top":top, "left":left});` I can see the input box close to the shape on top of it but not exact location

Comment: Cool, make a jsfiddle or similar to play about with. In the mean time have a try of this and see if it changes aything `$('#container').append('<input type="text" class="bpmnLabel" value="hi" autofocus style="position: absolute; top: top; left: left "/>');`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the jQuery style of appedning `css` rather than the `d3.js` you cold just do:

```js
var top = 100;
var left = 100;
$('#container').append('<input type="text" class="bpmnLabel" value="hi" autofocus/>')
$(".bpmnLabel").css({"position": "absolute", "top": top, "left": left});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

And here's a jsFiddle to play about with:

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/amkexysa/)

Comment: Thank you so much Alan. I did it this way 
                            `$('#myInput').css({"position": "absolute", "top": top + 165, "left": left + 150});` but some how its working when I add 165px to top and 15opx to left to make it look like it is top on the shape

Comment: @kittu no problem. If it worked for you could you select the answer as the correct one please?